# What was the significance of the pacing in The Straight Story?

Tags: analysis, the-straight-story

I've heard a few times that the pacing of The Straight Story makes sense at the end. **What does this refer to?**

I have watched it, and thought the pacing was appropriate for the nature of the film. I never had any revelatory moment though at the end where something happened that somehow 'justified it'.

Does it mean Alvin was taking this particularly laborious journey as some sort of penance? I don't see how that is revelatory, its continually stated throughout the whole film.